# Merge statement to remove duplicate values

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to remove the duplicate entries as following

```
Table abc

id name service_file_id
1   abc xyz
2   vbg xyz
2   vbg xyz
3   kio xyz
3   kio xyz
4   abc yzx
5   nji yzx
6   pop yzx

Table temp_table
service_file_id file_id
xyz             null
yzx             file_name_1
```

The table abc has duplicate entries for example

```
id name service_file_id
2  vbg  xyz
2  kio  xyz
```

I get the information about the duplicate entries via temp table. When a file_id in temp table is null, it means I have duplicate entries for that particular serivce_file_id

Below is the code I have tried

```
merge `abc` t

using (
  # choose a single row to delete the duplicates
  SELECT distinct a.* 
    FROM `abc` a
    left join `temp_table` b
    on a.service_file_id = b.file_id
    where b.file_id is not null

  )


ON FALSE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ROW
```

I can remove the duplicate entries from the table but it also deletes the rest of the data which is not duplicate.

```
current output
id name service_file_id
1  abc  xyz
2  vbg  xyz
3  kio  xyz

Desired output
id name service_file_id
1  abc  xyz
2  vbg  xyz
3  kio  xyz
4  abc  yzx
5  nji  yzx
6  pop  yzx
```

Could you please help me out here?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Without actually referencing the `temp_table` table you can delete the duplicates in your `abc` table just by using `merge` and `select distinct` :

```
merge `abc` t

using(
SELECT distinct a.*
    FROM `abc` a
)

ON FALSE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ROW
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Anjela B. The solution works on small dataset . For me I am trying to remove duplicates from roughly 6TB of data. I am not sure if the solution would be scalable in the case. Or may be I am wrong. Would there be any other solution than this?

Comment: It will work in a larger dataset, and is more efficient than the other approach I thought of. The other approach is to [create a table from a query result](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating_a_table_from_a_query_result) using the same query above with `DISTINCT`.